# kernlab sigest function arguments

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I would like to use the function **sigest()** of kernlab in Python to estimate a good range for sigmas that I'll use in the construction of RBF Kernels. I am using rpy2 but I can't figure out what would be the argument for "na_action".

**Recommended syntax in R:**

```r
sigest(x, frac = 0.5, scaled = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
```

**My syntax:**

```py
sigest(np.asmatrix(x), frac = 0.5, scaled = True, 
       na_action = pandas2ri.pandas.DataFrame.dropna)
```

x is the data matrix. I also tried

```py
sigest(np.asmatrix(x), frac = 0.5, scaled = True, 
       na_action = pd.DataFrame.dropna)
```

Libraries used: matplotlib ,numpy, pandas. Also numpy2ri and pandas2ri

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robj
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri 

rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
lab = importr("kernlab")

# ommiting the part of x initialization. it reads the data of a csv file and it's an array (40,1))
y = lab.sigest(np.asmatrix(x), frac = 0.5, scaled = True, na_action = 'ignore')
```

Comment: Please include all `library` and `import` lines. Did you mean R instead of Python here *kernlab in Python*?

Comment: No I meant python. Rpy2 helps you to use R's functions in python (https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/). The libraries I used in python are matplotlib ,numpy, pandas. Also numpy2ri and pandas2ri

Comment: I know `rpy2`. Please edit your post with all modules in each code block. How can `sigest` work in Python without assignment?

Comment: I am not using it without assignment. I just didn't think it would be necessary to add extra infos since i only asked for an argument. Just not to include many random stuff.

Comment: There is nothing random or unnecessary for a compilable, runnable [MCVE]!

Answer (score 0):

None of those Pandas methods will work for the *na.action* argument which expects an R call to [`stats::na.omit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/na.fail.html). Therefore, you must somehow reference this R method. Additionally, because the parameter maintains a `dot` in its name which is not allowed in identifiers of Python variables, consider adjusting parameter name manually with rpy2's [`SignatureTranslatedFunction`](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/robjects_functions.html) if it is not handled automatically with `importr`:

```
from rpy2.robjects.functions import SignatureTranslatedFunction
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

lab = importr('kernlab')
lab.sigest = SignatureTranslatedFunction(lab.sigest,
                                         init_prm_translate = {'na_action': 'na.action'})
```

Then, try passing the needed action call (to renamed parameter) as a string to avoid it being called directly by Python like you can for other methods, `t.test`, `cor.test`, `lm`, using same *na.action* argument:

```
y = lab.sigest(np.asmatrix(x), frac=0.5, scaled=True, na_action="na.omit")
```

Comment: I use the method you suggest but I get the following error: error in stats.na omit.default() argument object is missing with no default

Comment: I believe that you need to pass the function, not the result of a call to the function without any argument. Try: `y = lab.sigest(np.asmatrix(x), frac=0.5, scaled=True, na_action=stats.na_omit)`

Comment: Was just about to respond @Igautier. OP should try removing the open/close parentheses.

Comment: Actually, according to [kernlab docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kernlab/versions/0.9-27/topics/sigest), the default *is* `na.omit`. Try removing that argument entirely. Alternatively, try passing argument as string `...na_action="na.omit"`.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had posted an answer earlier but my internet is quite awful. The options I tried are : 

1) na_action = stats.na_omit (Error in .local(x, ...) : unused argument (na_action = function (object, ...) UseMethod("na.omit"))) and stats.na_omit() (Error in na.omit.default() : argument "object" is missing, with no default) 
2) na_action = na_omit & na_omit() 
3) omit the argument na_action (Error: Error in if (any(co)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed)

Comment: Regarding passing it as string, I got the following error : Error in .local(x, ...) : unused argument (na_action = "na.omit")

Comment: Since dot names are not allowed in Python, you need to translate `na.action` to `na_action`. See edit above and then try passing, `na.omit`, as string. Curious why removing that argument raises an error regarding missings. It may be your data. Might need to see content of `x`, especially output of `np.asmatrix(x)`.

Comment: @Parfait I've tried to test the method you suggested but the result is:  _Error in rep(scaled, ncol(x)) : invalid 'times' argument_